# How to make query Cloud Firestore by values

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

**Hello, I want to make a query for Google cloud Firestore by values**.

I tried like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query someQuery = db.collection(.someCollection);
if (someBoolean){
someQuery.whereEqualTo("SomeField", "SomeValue");
}
if (someBoolean2){
someQuery.whereEqualTo("SomeField2", "SomeValue2");
}
//etc
someQuery.limit(1);
someQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task){
if (task.isSuccessful()){
if (task.getResult().isEmpty()){
Log.d("LOG","NO DOCUMENTS FOUND");
}
else{
for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){
Log.d("LOG", document.getId()+"=>"+document.getData());}}
}
else{
Log.d("TAG", "---ERROR---");}
```

but it returns all documents in collection.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I forgot to put symbols in end:     }});

Comment: There is an `edit` link right under your question allowing you to improve your question. When you add the `}}};` at the end, I also recommend spending some time to properly indent the code. The easier you make it for folks to (quickly) read your question, the more likely someone is to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numerous places, you do this:

```
if (someBoolean){
    someQuery.whereEqualTo("SomeField", "SomeValue");
}
```

This RETURNS a new Query with the .where() condition added - it DOES NOT modify the original query. `someQuery` is exactly the same after.  You need to save the returned value, for example:

```
if (someBoolean){
    someQuery = someQuery.whereEqualTo("SomeField", "SomeValue");
}
```